# Modal BottomSheet infront of navigation bar

Tags: android, dialog, bottom-sheet, dialogfragment

I am trying my hands on `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to build a modal bottom sheet, but as you can see in the screenshot, instead of sliding up behind the navigation bar, it is infront of it.
This is WHILE sliding up. When it's completely up, it is above the navigation bar. But it looks ugly when it appears.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Code of BottomSheet class:

```
public class ExampleBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
private BottomSheetListener mListener;

public interface BottomSheetListener {
    void onButton1Clicked();
    void onButton2Clicked();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mListener = (BottomSheetListener) context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container);

    Button button1 = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onButton1Clicked();
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onButton2Clicked();
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
}
```

Opening BottomSheet in `MainActivity`:

```
Button buttonOpenBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.button_open_bottom_sheet);
    buttonOpenBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
            bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: No and I saw that it was the same in the Google apps, so I guess it's something we have to accept.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Why just not to add paddings depends on WindowInsets??

Comment: @HeyAlex Can you give an example for this?